# launch program on boot (debian server)

Tags: linux, debian

Path to folder: root/CumulusServer

Command to execute: ./CumulusServer --daemon [--pidfile=/var/run/CumulusServer.pid]

I've spent considerable time trying to figure out how to modify init.d? Any help would be appreciated in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you'd like to add it in /etc/rc.local like that:

```
cd /root/CumulusServer && ./CumulusServer --daemon
```

Comment: I didn't work for me. I tried /root/CumulusServer/CumulusServer --daemon and 
cd /root/CumulusServer && ./CumulusServer --daemon